# Comments with something else than percent sign/carriage return

Tags: comments, catcodes

AFAIK, LaTeX's comments are what is between a pair of characters with category code respectively:

- 14 (normally a `%`),
- 5  (normally an end of line).

Is it possible to define another pair of characters (say `@*`) such that all in between is discarded from the output? More explicitly, I want the output of:

```
foo @bar *baz
```

to be: "foo baz"

Note that my question is not how to define characters of categories 14 and 5: in particular, I don't want `@` to be of category 14 since I don't want all what follows on the current line to be discarded from the output.

Comment: But you are explicitly saying that you want to remove everything in between but at the same time `foo<space>@bar*<space>baz` should convert to `foo<space>baz` rather than the logic `foo<space><space>baz`?

Comment: @Manuel Indeed. I'll edit my question.

Comment: luatex a possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the first character active (catcode 13) and define it as a macro.

```
\catcode`\@=\active
\def@#1*{}
```

TeX will match everything after `@` up to the character `*` as `#1`, and then expand to the definition, which is blank. Use `\long\def` if you'd like to allow newlines between `@` and `*`

For example, it works with `foo @bar *baz` as the question asks:

[image: illustration]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\catcode`\@=\active
\long\def@#1*{}

% Because I use \verb below for illustration and I'd like the character @ to be treated verbatim too.
\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&\do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~\do\@}
% ^ The above is the standard definition of \dospecials, with "\do\@" appended. Could also write:
% \let \dospecialsOld = \dospecials
% \def\dospecials{\dospecialsOld\do\@}

foo baz (typed \verb|foo baz|)

foo %bar
baz (typed \verb|foo %bar<newline>baz|)

foo @bar
*baz (typed \verb|foo @bar<newline>*baz|)

foo @bar *baz (typed \verb|foo @bar *baz|)

\smallskip

foo @bar* baz (typed \verb|foo @bar* baz|)

foo {} baz (typed \verb|foo {} baz|)

\end{document}
```

Note that with this definition, the starting character `@` cannot be used for anything else by default (without changing its catcode again), just as with the usual catcodes the character `%` cannot be used for anything other than comments. (Also, for the character `@` in particular, note that using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` will clobber our definition and we'd have to set the catcode to `\active` again.)

Note also that the behaviour of skipping leading spaces on the next line, that you get with from-`%`–to-end-of-line comments, is different (to get it, you have to put the closing `*` after the spaces):

[image: spaces]

Comment: Nice! Unfortunately, I can't make it work in my real use case (much more complicated, involving LaTeX source code: printed thanks to `listings`, processed and resulting PDF included, `\newenvironment` involved, etc.). I'll try to see what's going on.

Comment: @Denis: Also make sure that `@` isn't used for anything else, as it tends to be in LaTeX code.  :-)

Comment: That's what I'm fighting against: almost all the characters I'm trying are used by at least one package I'm loading.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Another option is, instead of making a character active, use a short macro, like `\?` to delimit the comment.  You can use the same macro to close it out, via `\long\def\?#1\?{}`

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added some examples. Also, note that you probably want to define this *after* you've loaded the packages you want. Once all packages are loaded, the re-definition of `@` (or whatever character) should only affect input that comes later in the same file, and not what has been defined earlier. (And Steven's suggested option is also a good one, without messing with catcodes. In fact the *closing* character can be anything even if it has a different catcode, e.g. `\def\?#1${}` to start with `\?` and end with `$`.)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess it wouldn't be possible in my real use case: I need the characters to be escaping ones of `listings` as well (something like `escapeinside={@}{*}`).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Maybe if you ask another question with an example of the real use case (with `listings` and LaTeX source code etc. and why you need comments there), someone may be an alternative solution for that problem that does not involve comments… (E.g. maybe it's ok for TeX to see the stuff inside “comments”, if `listings` can later be persuaded to not typeset, or something like that.)

Answer (score 4):

If luatex is a possibility you can make the substitution on the text stream before TeX tokenizes the input, so before you need to worry about catcodes

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\directlua{
function at_star_comment (s)
return string.gsub(s,'@[^*]*\@percentchar*','')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", at_star_comment, "comment between @ and *")
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

foo @bar *baz


even mismatched braces \fbox{zz@  lose this brace} * this gets boxed} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to stay away from `luatex` as long as possible since my real document (based on `beamer` class) takes quite a long time to compile with `pdflatex` and that's significantly worse with `luatex` :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé you could of course do the equivalent filter of the input buffer with pdflatex if instead of processing the source file you process the output of `sed -e -s/@[^\*]*\*/g' file.tex`

Comment: Indeed but I'd like to stay away from external tools as well. I'm very demanding, am I not? :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé there is the other answer (discarding the text as a macro argument) but like any macro argument, that is hard to make work if you want read the text verbatim and skip over mis-matched braces as in my example (or `%` etc)